# How to fix 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python

Please tell me why when I start the program I get the error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
def binary_search(array: list, element: int, start: int, end: int, counter: int) -> (int, int):
    counter += 1
    mid = (start + end) // 2
    
    if element == array[mid]:
        return mid, counter
    if element < array[mid]:
        return binary_search(array, element, start, mid-1, counter), counter
    else:
        return binary_search(array, element, mid+1, end, counter), counter

array = parse("input.txt")
n = size(array)
binaryComparisonsSum = 0

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    array = array.sort()

    result, binaryComparisons = binary_search(array, array[i], 0, len(array), 0)
    binaryComparisonsSum += binaryComparisons
```

I was expecting to get the element I'm looking for and the amount of action to find it, but I see an error

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your question.

Comment: The `sort` function sorts in place. It returns None. Change `array = array.sort()` to `array.sort()`.

Comment: @jarmod and they do it that way on purpose, so when you make this mistake you'll catch it fast.

Comment: Why do you sort `array` on every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing:

```py
array = array.sort()
```

will make `array` `None` and then you try to subscript `array` by doing `array[i]`. Instead you only need:

```py
array.sort()
```

This is because the `.sort()` function sorts the list *in place* and does not return a sorted list.

Also it would be good practice to call `array.sort()` *before* the `for` loop as it is unnecessary to sort it more than once.